# C# SMS need HELP

Tags: c#, java, sms

I have an C# application that need to sms to IT administrator.

My supervisor mention to me that he do not want additional cost involve in this application, which mean GSM modem is not applicable.

He gave me an IP and port number, username and Password.
The IP, port number, username and password is given when we subscribe a broadband and i comes with an SMS service. The username is to log in to [this website](http://www.infoblast.com.my/home/) and after log in, it allowed to compose SMS. The website does not have any API.
The IP is refer to the DNS >>> http://www.infoblast.com.my/home/.

I have seen some topic about SMS gateway but that is not what needed, I also try some `SMTPClient` API from C# which is able to send email and convert to SMS, the requirement is `[number]@[provider].com` which my telecommunication company does not provide.

Is there anyway to do it??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but: "Besides C# maybe other language is able to do it??" - languages have nothing to do with it at all. Every language which is turing-complete and allow you to do calls to the operating system can "do" it.

Comment: so any solution for my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

if that's a "normal website" you will need to work with something like `HttpWebRequest` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or use perhaps even use `WebBrowser` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) to simulate what a user would do on the website to send SMS.